# What are the items billable in softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Which API can I use to get items eligible for billing in a softlayer account. For eg: Virtual guests , bare metal servers , storage , network etc. If API is not there what all categories of devices are eligible for billing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, there not exists a specific API call, to retrieve items billable, but you can get the items with their categories (categoryCode) for your next invoice.

The following Rest call will help with it:

```
https://$user$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems?objectMask=mask[orderItem[item]]

Method: Get
```

Also, you can retrieve the items which belong an specific invoice:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/8141353/getItems.json?objectMask=mask[id, billingItem[orderItem[item]]]

Method: Get
```

Replace: 8141353 with your invoiceId.

References:

- [SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems)
- [SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice::getItems](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/getItems)

> Updated

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems.json?objectMask=mask[category[group]]

Method: Get
```

Comment: I can see category code as 'server' and 'guest_core' there is no way we can idenfiy if server is virtual guest or bare metal server. Also what category code does. a storage infra get? Or a network infrastructure get?

Comment: Please, see updated section in my answer, perhaps that object mask can help.